# php dropdown menu to be placed in the html table

Tags: php

i have done this dropdown menu which takes the distinct POS from my database. and it is displayed out as how the attached picture shows. [image]

however i want the php dropdown menu to be placed in the html table instead. as shown in the 2nd picture. so i can update the particular field. but i don't know how to do it, do help! :)

```
<td><input type="text" name="POS" placeholder="POS" required />

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('ishop');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT POS FROM tbl_st";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='POS'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['POS'] ."'>" . $row['POS'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>


</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: Paste in a fiddle for this

Comment: I think you are expecting the dropdown to be a part of the input field which is not possible. I dont know the business logic so its difficult to suggest a solution.

Comment: Your input field is occupying 100% space in `<td>`, give width as 50% to inout and try once.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td><input type="text" name="POS" placeholder="POS" required />

    <?php
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('ishop');

        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT POS FROM tbl_st";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        echo "<select name='POS'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row['POS'] ?>"><?php echo  $row['POS'] ?></option>;
        <?php
        }
        echo "</select>";
    ?>


</td>
```

Comment: mm nope, it doesn't work! still appears to be the same way haha!

Comment: remove this `<input type="text" name="POS" placeholder="POS" required />` top of `<td>`

Comment: nope, i think you don't get what i mean. what i want is to have the dropdown box to be inside the table, so that i can update the particular field.

Comment: @Celine.Tan your dropdown box is inside the table - it's just not on the same line as the input field is. and that has nothing to do with updating a field.